# How to auto resize view in Lua used Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I create new Tabbar based project in Corona.
Then I change file build.settings to support landscape orientation

```
orientation = {
    default = "portrait",
    supported = { "portrait","landscapeLeft","landscapeRight" }
},
```

### The problem is that the view don't resize when rotate to landscape.

[image]

### How to enable autoresize in Lua using Corona SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Corona SDK gives you autoresize out of the box. I think you are supposed to listen for the 'orientation' event on the Runtime object to be notified when the device is rotated, then reposition your controls accordingly.

See the [Events and Listeners](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/events-and-listeners) section of the Corona SDK documentation (search for 'orientation' on that page).

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is not entirely correct. You should be listening to [event.resize](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/resize/index.html) and not [event.orientation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/orientation/index.html).

From the [orientation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/orientation/index.html) docs:

> However, for apps with multiple supported orientations, the orientation event should not be used to re-layout the UI — instead, the resize event should be used.